# cant Pass the playlist tracks from the Playlist component to the TrackList component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im currently working on a project, however after looking through my code several times I am still unable to Pass the playlist tracks from the Playlist component to the TrackList component.

this is my webpage: http://localhost:3000/
[image: web page]

my webpage is supposed to look like this: [image] with the info from the results replicated on the new playlist section as well:

the tracklist component shows when imported to the results component but doesn't show when imported to the playlist (new playlist) component on  the right hand side of the web page

results component:

```
import React from 'react';

import './SearchResults.css';

import TrackList from '../../TrackList/TrackList';

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
   render () {
    return (
        <div className="SearchResults">
        <h2>Results</h2>     
        <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults} 
                    onAdd = {this.props.onAdd}
                    isRemoval={false} /> 
      </div>   
    )
   }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

Playlist component:

```
import React from 'react';

import './Playlist.css';

import TrackList from '../TrackList/TrackList';

class Playlist extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (
        <div className="Playlist">
        <input defaultValue={"New Playlist"} />
        <TrackList tracks={this.props.playlistTracks} /> 
        <button className="Playlist-save">SAVE TO SPOTIFY</button>
</div>
       ) 
    }
}

export default Playlist;
```

Tracklist component:

```
import React from "react";

import './TrackList.css';

import Track from "../Track/Track";

class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div class="TrackList">  
            {      
            this.props.tracks?.map(track => {
              return <Track track={track}
              key={track.id} 
              onAdd={this.props.onAdd} />
            })
        } 
</div>
      ) 
    }
}

export default TrackList;
```

any help or guidance woud be greatly appreciated.